# Need help reading from a text file and outputting to a csv

Tags: powershell

```
$sb = {
    write-host "Get_Registry_Value.ps1"
    Get-ChildItem HKLM:\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\McAfee\AVSolution\DS -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object { Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath }
    }
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb -ComputerName xxx-xxx
```

Comment: Thanks Prasoon, I am trying to read the host from a text file and then out putting them to a csv file, so far I can only enter one host at a time after -ComputerName

Comment: `Invoke-Command` can  accept a _list_ of systems in the  `-ComputerName` parameter. [*grin*]

Comment: Hi Lee I am new to powershell if you could provide the syntax please

Comment: i don't have any mcaffee stuff, so i am curious what you are seeking at that location. for me, a similar location for `Python` contains things like `(default)      : C:\Python38\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw` plus a bunch of things that powershell adds [usually prefixed with `PS`]. so what do you want to add to your CSV from those items?

Comment: The path contains the Mcafee DAT file information it shows when it was udated and the time so basically the registry will tell if the Antivirus is updated using powershell

Comment: please post the details you get - add them to your Original Post - so that i can make the CSV meaningful. otherwise i will have to use something from my system as a placeholder.

Comment: Please use a placeholder

Comment: done! i hope it makes sense ... the  data is rather peculiar seeming. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to get info from the registry of several systems. since i don't have any mcaffee software, i used Python as a placeholder. the code  comments seem adequate, but feel free to ask for clarification. [*grin*]

```
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

# fake reading in a list of systems
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$SystemList = @'
LocalHost
10.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
BetterNotBeThere
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$sb = {
    $RegPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8'
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath  $RegPath -Recurse |
        ForEach-Object {
            Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath
            }
    }

# the "-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" will make PoSh NOT show error on the screen
#    if you need to get a list of non-responders, you can compare the input list to the items in "$Results"
$Results = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb -ComputerName $SystemList -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$Results |
    # filter out the items with no path info or lots of extra properties
    Where-Object {
        $_.'(default)'
        } |
    # remove unwanted properties & add a ComputerName prop
    Select-Object -Property @{n = 'ComputerName'; e = {$_.PSComputerName}}, * -ExcludeProperty 'RunspaceId', 'PSShowComputerName' |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$env:TEMP\powershelltek_HKLM-Software-Info.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

the 1st item in $Results ...

```
(default)      : C:\Python38\Doc\python380.chm
PSPath         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\Help\Main Python 
                 Documentation
PSParentPath   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\Help
PSChildName    : Main Python Documentation
PSProvider     : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
PSComputerName : LocalHost
RunspaceId     : a915a91a-5cfd-405f-ac0a-b3350cd90942
```

content of the CSV file ...

```
"ComputerName","(default)","PSPath","PSParentPath","PSChildName","PSProvider","PSComputerName"
"LocalHost","C:\Python38\Doc\python380.chm","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\Help\Main Python Documentation","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\Help","Main Python Documentation","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry","LocalHost"
"LocalHost","C:\Python38\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\Idle","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8","Idle","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry","LocalHost"
"LocalHost","1","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\IdleShortcuts","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8","IdleShortcuts","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry","LocalHost"
"LocalHost","C:\Python38\","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\InstallPath","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8","InstallPath","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry","LocalHost"
"LocalHost","C:\Python38\Lib\;C:\Python38\DLLs\","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\PythonPath","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8","PythonPath","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry","LocalHost"
"127.0.0.1","C:\Python38\Doc\python380.chm","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\Help\Main Python Documentation","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\Help","Main Python Documentation","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry","127.0.0.1"
"127.0.0.1","C:\Python38\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\Idle","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8","Idle","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry","127.0.0.1"
"127.0.0.1","1","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\IdleShortcuts","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8","IdleShortcuts","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry","127.0.0.1"
"127.0.0.1","C:\Python38\","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\InstallPath","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8","InstallPath","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry","127.0.0.1"
"127.0.0.1","C:\Python38\Lib\;C:\Python38\DLLs\","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\PythonPath","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8","PythonPath","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry","127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: In $SystemList = @' can you clarify the usage

Comment: the  `$SystemList` section is just a way to provide a sample set of system names. the code SHOULD work exactly as-is on your system. as the comment implies [`in real life, use Get-Content`], when you are ready to use real system names, load them with `Get-Content`, `Import-CSV`, OR via something like `Get-ADComputer`.

Comment: Hi Lee the script runs fine but when I use Get-Content -Path to get the host list  it will error out with:  Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty Provide an argument that is not null or empty

Comment: @powershelltek - that means you have a problem loading the file. [*grin*] is anything in `$SystemList` at that point? also, how did you replace that section of code? the _simplest_ is to add a `$SystemList = Get-Content` line AFTER the  entire block - and then either delete or comment out the block that ends with `'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine`. that entire here-string is unneeded once you have your own test [or real] data.

Comment: Lee the script runs with not error now after adding the Get-Content, the csv file is created but there is not data in it

Comment: @powershelltek - so the standard diagnostics come into play. [*grin*] **_[1]_** what is in `$Results`? **_[2]_** what do you get if you comment out the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` at the end of the `$Results = ` line?